# Calender style does not apply in custom wpf datepicker

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker, custom-controls

I want some custom functionality with new styles on wpf date picker control. So,I extended WPF date picker control. I created a class in a control library project like below:

```
public class MaskedDatePicker : DatePicker
{

  static MaskedDatePicker()
  {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MaskedDatePicker),
          new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MaskedDatePicker)));
  }

  public override void OnApplyTemplate()
  {
  }

}
```

After that I created styles in Themes/Generic.xaml in the same project.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MaskedDatePicker}">
...
<Setter Property="CalendarStyle" Value="{DynamicResource CalendarStyle}" />
<Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
...
</Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="DatePickerTextBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DatePickerTextBox}">
...
</Style>

<Style x:Key="CalendarStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Calendar}">
<Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Calendar}">
                <StackPanel x:Name="PART_Root" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <CalendarItem x:Name="PART_CalendarItem"
                                  Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                  BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                  BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                  Style="{DynamicResource CalendarItemStyle}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="CalendarItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type CalendarItem}">
......
</Style>
```

Now I am facing an issue that when i consume this control in a test project the styles for DatePickerTextbox are applied in datepicker but styles for Calender control does not get applied and default calender is visible in Window.

Comment: change target type of calender and try <Style x:Key="CalendarStyle" TargetType="{x:Type local:MaskedDatePicker}">

Comment: Setting Target type to MaskedDateTimePicker gives compile time errors.

Comment: change here also in ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Calendar}" in style

Comment: I changed it for Control template as well. But after that i was getting errors for following peroperties in same style:                      <Setter Property="CalendarDayButtonStyle" Value="{StaticResource CalendarDayButtonStyle}" />
        <Setter Property="CalendarButtonStyle" Value="{StaticResource CalendarButtonStyle}" />. Even after commnenting these Calender picks default style.

Comment: Sorry I said wrong solution to you..you need to edit default style of datepicker..... goto designer->right click on datepicker->edit template->edit copy->..now  replace  x:Name="PART_Root" and DatePickerTextBox in default style with your designed template and set style/controltemplate target type TargetType="{x:Type local:MaskedDatePicker}">

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I already have the template updated for the PART_Root and DatePickerTextBox in style. It would be great if you can  share a dummy calender template used in DatePicker.